# VBA - vlookup is running to runtime error '13'

Tags: excel, vba, macros, runtime-error, vlookup

I am fairly new to VBA and I would like to create a VLOOKUP macro, but consequently facing the same issue, when the VLOOKUP cannot find the value from the range it runs into runtime error '13' Type mismatch.

What I want the macro to do is for each line item in TOTAL sheet find the value from OLA list sheet and it does it, except for the ones that are not included in the OLA list sheet, for them I want it to write "NA".

See my code below:

```
Sub elsovlookup()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim test As String
    Dim size As Long

    size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("TOTAL").Columns(1)) + 1

        For i = 3 To size

        cell = Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "U")
        test = Application.VLookup(cell, Worksheets("OLA list").Range("K:R"), 8, False)
        If IsError(test) Then
            test = "NA"
            Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "AC") = "OLA not found"
        Else:
            Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "AC") = "OLA found"
        End If
        Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "V") = test
    Next i

    MsgBox "First vlookup is complete."
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: When you debug-through what is your "cell" coming back as? Mine is showing as Empty, though this may be to do with my dummy data that I whacked in. I had thought this is because Worksheets.Cells is expecting rowindex and columnindex as it's arguments and you've used "U" as a string instead of a number.

Comment: `Application.VLookup` will return a `Variant`. This is either the value of the successful `VLOOKUP`ed cell or an `Error` value. But an `Error` value does not fit into `String`. That's why `Dim test As Variant` is needed.

Comment: @Tim Edwards: The "U" in `Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "U")` means the column `U`. So you must put something  into `U3` in `Worksheets("TOTAL")`. Then you will get that back if `i` is 3.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, I'd only used cells() with numbers, wasn't aware you could mix given i is a long.

Comment: Thank you @AxelRichter, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. It will work

```
Sub elsovlookup()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim size As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("TOTAL").Columns(1)) + 1
    For i = 3 To size
        Set cell = Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "U")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("OLA list").Range("K:K"), cell.Value) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "AC") = "OLA found"
        Else
            Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "AC") = "OLA not found"
        End If
        Worksheets("TOTAL").Cells(i, "V") = test
    Next i
    MsgBox "First vlookup is complete."
End Sub
```